# Alfresco 5.0C advanced search Get slingshot search parameters

Tags: json, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, aikau

When you make an advanced search in Alfresco it returns a json response with results executing the script

```
http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/slingshot/search/?facetFields=..
```

I have add a button in the aikau advanced search results page and I want to execute the same script. How can I call it and get its parameters ?

The aikau button

```
var button = {
  name: "alfresco/buttons/AlfButton",
   config: {
            label: "Exec Script",
            additionalCssClasses: "call-to-action",
            onClick:....... **call facets script**...
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if possible I would recommend that you move up to using Alfresco 5.0.d as this will enable you to take advantage of the weekly releases of [Aikau](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau) as described in [this](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/developer/2015/03/24/why-alfresco-5-0-d-will-be-a-game-changer-for-ui-development/) blog post.

As for your specific question... you should not be attempting to define an Aikau button like that (with the "onClick" attribute). Aikau works over a publication/subscription mechanism so buttons would be configured with a `publishTopic` and a `publishPayload`. The topic published would need to be subscribed to by another widget or a service.

If you're not familiar with working with Aikau then I suggest that you work through the [tutorial on GitHub](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/blob/master/tutorial/chapters/About.md). You can also find an additional list of educational references [here](https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/wiki/Education-References).